# Java: randomly generating circles that do not intersect (stuck in while loop)

Tags: java

I want to create random circles on a canvas, with a restriction. Namely, none of the circles should intersect. I have so far come up with a check to see if the circles intersect, and if they do, it generates a new one. Here is my reasoning along with the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<amountRBC;i++)
        {
            xPosRBC[i]=random.nextInt(xSize);
            yPosRBC[i]=random.nextInt(ySize);
        }
```

Over here, I generate a random x and y position (inside the canvas of xSize by ySize) for every RBC (a total of amountRBC, for demonstration purposes, let's say 5). These x and y positions get stored in the array xPosRBC[] and yPosRBC[] respectively.

```
for(int i=0;i<amountRBC;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<amountRBC;j++)
            {
                while(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(xPosRBC[j]-xPosRBC[i]),2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(yPosRBC[j]-yPosRBC[i]), 2))<(2*rbcRadius))
                {
                    xPosRBC[i]=random.nextInt(xSize); //random starting position of bacterium
                    yPosRBC[i]=random.nextInt(ySize);
                    j=0;
                }
            }
        }
```

then I check for every point whether they are less than 2*radius of the circle apart (using this sqrt((|xpos1-xpos2|)^2+(|ypos1-ypos2|)^2) formula) and if they are, a new position is generated and the "checking" for-loop gets reset (j=0). Repeat this process for every circle there is (from i=0 to amountRBC). In my reasoning this should end up with 5 random placed circles, which all have a distance of at least 2*radius apart, which means they should not intersect.
However, the program seems to get stuck in this while-loop indefinitely and I can't seem to find out why.

[NOTE]: there are only a small amount of circles, with a small radius on a large canvas. This means that the case that there isn't enough screen to fill up the circles cannot be the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it gets stuck, then it probably randomly generated a surface where it's now impossible to add a non-intersecting circle. Just add a failure counter, and if it generates too much intersecting circles in a row, then abort algorithm. Show some message about only being able to set `n` circles out of `m` and you good to go.

Comment: Not a direct solution, but an idea for a different approach: how about you divide your canvas into a grid, let's say of 20 by 20 cells, each big enough to contain a *bacterium*, then you loop over those and, with a certain probability, create a *bacterium*. The probability can be calculated from the number of cells and `amountRBC`. Then, if you are to create a *bacterium*, you just randomize its position *within* the cell in order to make it less obvious. This way, you only need one loop, yay! I feel like playing a round of agario now...

Comment: @M.Prokhorov that would make sense if there were a lot of circles, however, it even gets stuck inside the loop when it only has to draw a single circle.

Comment: little improvement: do not calculate the square root, just compare to the square of 2*r

Comment: And if you square the difference anyway, there's no need to take absolute value first.

Answer (score 2):

I have just found out the solution to the problem. Namely, in said while loop, it also compared the size of the circle to its own position, so that distance will always be 0. In the while loop I've added the operant (&& i!=j) and now it seems to be working fine. Thanks guys!

Comment: same as Persixty answered

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger It is. The OP's answer popped up as I clicked submit. NB: There's actually a more efficient way of doing the comparison. This approach compares A to B then B to A and essentially doubles the effort.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to execute the inner loop as follows:

```
for(int j=0;j<amountRBC;j++) {
    if(j==i){
        continue;
    }
```

As it stands when `j` is equal to `i` it will find that circle intersects itself, regenerate and reset `j`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are stuck in the while loop, but the for loop, since you reset the inner for loop's counter `j=0;` inside the while loop it will never finish.

Validate that with some printouts and you should see where you get stuck. Also helps to print out (or debug) to see which condition fails to be what you expect, and what the contents are.